# Delete all associated records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a few tables like below.

[image: Tables]

Each table has a primary key `<tablename>_id`. Unfortunately, there is no foreign key setup on other tables even when a table is referencing the primary key of another table (for example: `table2`, `table2_1` are referencing `table1.table1_id`), and I am not allowed to change this design now.

I need to delete all the associated records when a record is deleted from a table based on the primary key.

Illustration:

If I delete a record with `table1_id = 10` in `table1`, I should also delete the records in the other tables where `table1_id` is part of the table structure (`table2` and `table2_1` in this case). When a record is deleted in the `table2`, then I should also delete the records in the other tables where `table2_id` is part of the table structure (`table3` in this case), I need to traverse until there are no dependencies and delete all associated records.

I have tried to produce queries like below (assume I would like to delete a record where table1_is=10):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (table1_id INT IDENTITY(10, 1), table1_field1 varchar(100), table1_field2 BIT);
CREATE TABLE table2 (table2_id INT IDENTITY(100, 1), table2_field1 varchar(100), table2_field2 BIT, table1_id INT);
CREATE TABLE table2_1 (table2_1_id INT IDENTITY(500, 1), table2_1_field1 varchar(100), table2_1_field2 BIT, table1_id INT);
CREATE TABLE table3 (table3_id INT IDENTITY(1000, 1), table3_field1 varchar(100), table3_field2 BIT, table2_id INT);
CREATE TABLE table4 (table4_id INT IDENTITY(10000, 1), table4_field1 varchar(100), table4_field2 BIT, table3_id INT);
CREATE TABLE table5 (table5_id INT IDENTITY(100000, 1), table5_field1 varchar(100), table5_field2 BIT, table4_id INT);

INSERT INTO table1(table1_field1, table1_field2) VALUES ('table1_field1_1', 0), ('table1_field1_2', 1), ('table1_field1_3', 0), ('table1_field1_4', 1);
INSERT INTO table2(table2_field1, table2_field2, table1_id) VALUES ('table2_field1_1', 0, 10), ('table2_field1_2', 1, 11), ('table2_field1_3', 0, 12), ('table2_field1_4', 1, 13);
INSERT INTO table2_1(table2_1_field1, table2_1_field2, table1_id) VALUES ('table2_1_field1_1', 0, 10), ('table2_1_field1_2', 1, 11), ('table2_1_field1_3', 0, 12), ('table2_1_field1_4', 1, 13);
INSERT INTO table3(table3_field1, table3_field2, table2_id) VALUES ('table3_field1_1', 0, 100), ('table3_field1_2', 1, 101), ('table3_field1_3', 0, 102), ('table3_field1_4', 1, 103);
INSERT INTO table4(table4_field1, table4_field2, table3_id) VALUES ('table4_field1_1', 0, 1000), ('table4_field1_2', 1, 1001), ('table4_field1_3', 0, 1002), ('table4_field1_4', 1, 1003);
INSERT INTO table5(table5_field1, table5_field2, table4_id) VALUES ('table5_field1_1', 0, 10000), ('table5_field1_2', 1, 10001), ('table5_field1_3', 0, 10002), ('table5_field1_4', 1, 10003);
SELECT * FROM table1
SELECT * FROM table2
SELECT * FROM table2_1
SELECT * FROM table3
SELECT * FROM table4
SELECT * FROM table5

    select t.name, c.name, 'DELETE [' + t.name + '] WHERE [' + c.name + '] = 10',
    'SELECT t.name [tn], c.name [cn] FROM sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id where c.name=''' + t.name + '_id'' and t.name<>''' + t.name + ''' ' 
    from sys.tables t
    inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id
    where c.name='table1_id' and t.name<>'table1'
    order by t.name

    /* Use the SELECT queries to find other dependencies like below */

SELECT t.name [t], c.name [c],'SELECT t.name [tn], c.name [cn] FROM sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id where c.name=''' + t.name + '_id'' and t.name<>''' + t.name + '''' 
FROM sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id where c.name='table2_id' and t.name<>'table2'

SELECT t.name [tn], c.name [cn], 'SELECT t.name [tn], c.name [cn] FROM sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id where c.name=''' + t.name + '_id'' and t.name<>''' + t.name + '''' 
FROM sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id where c.name='table3_id' and t.name<>'table3'

SELECT t.name [tn], c.name [cn], 'SELECT t.name [tn], c.name [cn] FROM sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id where c.name=''' + t.name + '_id'' and t.name<>''' + t.name + '''' 
FROM sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id where c.name='table4_id' and t.name<>'table4'

SELECT t.name [tn], c.name [cn] FROM sys.tables t inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id where c.name='table5_id' and t.name<>'table5'

/* I need to run the SQL queries something like below */
DELETE table5 where table4_id in (select table4_id from table4 where table3_id in (select table3_id from table3 where table2_id in (select table2_id from table2 where table1_id=10)))
DELETE table4 where table3_id in (select table3_id from table3 where table2_id in (select table2_id from table2 where table1_id=10))
DELETE table3 where table2_id in (select table2_id from table2 where table1_id=10)
DELETE table2 where table1_id=10
DELETE table2_1 where table1_id=10
DELETE table1 where table1_id=10
```

I expect the following results after deletion:

[image: Expected Results]

**NOTE:**

1. Please note I am aware of how foreign key relations will be useful in this scenario, but I am not allowed to change the tables structure/design now (i.e. cannot add the foreign keys).
2. I cannot add triggers as well.
3. I would like to achieve the desired results with T-SQL / dynamic SQL.
4. I have used only 5 tables in my illustration, but it can be n number of tables in the similar structure.

Could anyone advice any alternatives ways (or automate this) so I just pass the table1.table1_id, then it should delete all associated records, please?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: I think you can solve your problem by adding a trigger that will delete the record on the associated table when you delete it from the main table. But I'm not sure of your specific problem.

Comment: @TomH : updated the question, thanks.

Comment: @NWest updated the question, I cannot add triggers. Thanks

Comment: What about stored procedures? A stored procedure with a single argument (the initial id) could do the job for you.

Comment: @cars10 could you help me in writing a stored procedure, please?

Comment: Do you need a script for ONE time run or may be scheduled job? Or You want to control that whenever a delete operation happens for an ID say table1_id 10 , then all respective rows should be deleted, like as a part of a delete operation in an application?

Answer (score 0):

standard way to solve this is to have foreign keys/triggers, but as soon as you cannot use them, you have to maintain integrity differently:

so, you need stored procedure to do the following:

```
delete from table1 where table1_id = ####;
delete from table2 where table1_id not in (select table1_id from table1);
delete from table2_1 where table1_id not in (select table1_id from table1);
delete from table3 where table2_id not in (select table2_id from table2);
delete from table4 where table3_id not in (select table3_id from table3);
delete from table5 where table4_id not in (select table4_id from table4);
```

this will delete row from table1 and then all "invalid" rows from other tables

Answer (score 0):

Something like this if a stored procedure is allowed:

```
CREATE PROC delrec @id int AS
BEGIN
 DELETE table5 where table4_id in 
  (select table4_id from table4 where table3_id in 
    (select table3_id from table3 where table2_id in 
      (select table2_id from table2 where table1_id=@id)))
 DELETE table4 where table3_id in 
  (select table3_id from table3 where table2_id in 
    (select table2_id from table2 where table1_id=@id))
 DELETE table3 where table2_id in 
  (select table2_id from table2 where table1_id=@id)
 DELETE table2 where table1_id=@id
 DELETE table2_1 where table1_id=@id
 DELETE table1 where table1_id=@id
END
```